# vagrant : chef_solo | how i can change log path from mysql server and mongodb?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm working with vagrant and chef .
As far as everything goes , only when I use the Logpath of mysql and mongodb change in the vagrant file , I get an error.

if anyone here has a tip and can help me would be happy.

In Vagrantfile I have stated so ...

```
:mysql => {
        :server_root_password => 'password',
        :server_debian_password => 'password',
        :server_repl_password => 'password',
        :allow_remote_root => true,
        :log_dir => "/vagrant/www/logs/mysql",
        :tunable => {
          :log_slow_queries => "/vagrant/www/logs/mysql/slow.log",
          :log_error => true,
          :log_warnings => true
        }
},
:mongodb => {
      :logpath => "/vagrant/www/logs/mongodb"
},



================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'directory[/vagrant/www/logs/mysql]'
================================================================================

Errno::EPERM
------------
Operation not permitted - /vagrant/www/logs/mysql

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/server.rb

117:     directory path do
118:       owner     'mysql' unless platform?('windows')
119:       group     'mysql' unless platform?('windows')
120:       action    :create
121:       recursive true
122:     end
123:   end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/server.rb:117:in `block in from_file'

directory("/vagrant/www/logs/mysql") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Directory
  action [:create]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  path "/vagrant/www/logs/mysql"
  recursive true
  cookbook_name :mysql
  recipe_name "server"
  owner "mysql"
  group "mysql"
  mode 493
end

[2013-10-31T01:03:09-07:00] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: Errno::EPERM - directory[/vagrant/www/logs/mysql] (mysql::server line 117) had an error: Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - /vagrant/www/logs/mysql
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

This line is the key problem: `Operation not permitted - /vagrant/www/logs/mysql`

which means it does not allow user to create directory under this path. Please check if user `mysql` is privileged to access directory `/vagrant/www/logs`. Maybe you need `+x` on `/vagrant`

Comment: It cost me a day or so of my life but changing permissions on shared folders isn't straightforward as adding +x, at least not on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not advise using this -- slow log writes will slow down most databases and I wouldn't want to do that to myself.

Anyhow, permissions on vagrant shared folders can be a bit tricky -- in some, if not many, cases you need to set owner / permission from the vagrantfile. This is a bit tricky for /vagrant but you could map another folder if you really don't want to vagrant ssh into the server to read the logs. To do so:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "logs", "/logs", :mount_options => ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777']
```

777 is probably overkill but you get the idea.